# Error while using Attach Api

Tags: java, instrumentation, agent, attach-api

While using attach API in Eclipse error is thrown in console.

In order to use attach API  I went to installed JRE in eclipse and then using edit option included the tools.jar in the external jars option in current JRE.

But it throws the following error when i try to execute a simple program such as

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no attach in java.library.path
>   com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers
>   installed     at
>   com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:190)
>     at dynamicLoadingTest.VMAttach.main(VMAttach.java:17)

This is the simple program executed.
    import java.io.IOException;

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;

public class VMAttach {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach("6832");
        } catch (AttachNotSupportedException e) {
            System.out.println("This error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The process id mentioned *6832* is of a Java application running on the system

On changing the installed jre to jdk following error is produced

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: jvm.dll not loaded by target process
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.<init>(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:46)
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(WindowsAttachProvider.java:52)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
    at dynamicLoadingTest.VMAttach.main(VMAttach.java:17)
```

Comment: Seems you need to add library again

Comment: yeah this problem is also originating on my system also.

Comment: @sansix i have done it again but the the problem remains

Comment: @SanyamGoel try looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565356/java-attach-api-changing-java-library-path-dynamically

Comment: @sanix i have checked the java library path it contains the path to jdk library where the tools.jar is located

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, This problem orignates when you have diffrent jdks in your system and all are included on the class path.

Comment: Can this answer be expanded on?  How would this be detected and/or solved?

Answer (score 3):

For me, the solution was to put `attach.dll` from the JDK (same version as your JRE) into the JRE's `bin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same with JDK1.7 and it is working fine. With JDK1.6 the problem remains .