# Setting Djava.library.path programmatically (or alternatives)?

Tags: java, jvm

I am looking to set the VM argument *Djava.library.path* programmatically. If this can't be done, what are the alternatives (if there are any)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565356/java-attach-api-changing-java-library-path-dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at this java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

you want to call the setProperty(String, String) method.

so it would look something like this in your case

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path","value_you_want");
```

Comment: looks like you are correct for that system property as it is only read once at startup. http://fahdshariff.blogspot.jp/2011/08/changing-java-library-path-at-runtime.html

Answer (score 11):

The solution is easy with this method:

```
public static void addLibraryPath(String pathToAdd) throws Exception {
    Field usrPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
    usrPathsField.setAccessible(true);

    String[] paths = (String[]) usrPathsField.get(null);

    for (String path : paths)
        if (path.equals(pathToAdd))
            return;

    String[] newPaths = Arrays.copyOf(paths, paths.length + 1);
    newPaths[newPaths.length - 1] = pathToAdd;
    usrPathsField.set(null, newPaths);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice hack, if some 3rd-party library uses System.loadLibrary(...), which you cannot change yourself! Ty!

Comment: Nice for JDK8, but did you already find out how to port this to JDK17?

Answer (score 3):

`java.library.path` is used when you load a dynamic library with System.loadLibrary(String libname).  System.load(String filename) uses full file name and does not need `java.library.path`.